# Using COPY to import a .json file into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, weather

I want to import some weather data (temperature, wind speed, ...) that is all formatted in a JSON file into a PostgreSQL 11 table so I can then make queries on that data.

I've been able to manually insert some data into a table but that's only OK because it's a small amount of data and I'm planning on using a LOT more data afterwards. Here is what I've found using the INSERT function: https://datavirtuality.com/blog-json-in-postgresql/.

That's why I've been trying to use the COPY function but no luck so far, even after having read a lot of stuff on different sources on the Internet ...

The JSON file is downloadable there : https://queueresults.meteoblue.com/F2637B90-45BB-4E7A-B47C-C34CD56674B3 (let me know if the file doesn't exist anymore).

I've been able to import the JSON file as text into a table with:

```
create table temp_json (values text);
copy temp_json from '/home/cae/test.json';
```

But I don't think that's the best approach to be able to make efficient queries later on ...

I usually run into the following error during my tests:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: [
```

as if I'm not able to parse the JSON file and the array properly within PostgreSQL ...

Thanks for your help !

Edit: Here is the content of the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "locationNames": [
        "59.4°N/24.7°E31.7m",
        "59.4°N/24.8°E36.4m"
      ],
      "coordinates": [
        [
          24.7,
          59.4,
          31.73
        ],
        [
          24.8,
          59.4,
          36.445
        ]
      ]
    },
    "domain": "NEMS12",
    "codes": [
      {
        "unit": "°C",
        "dataPerTimeInterval": [
          {
            "data": [
              [
                -0.395,
                -0.195,
                -0.099999994,
                -0.030000001,
                -0.060000002,
                -0.099999994,
                -0.099999994,
                0.005,
                -0.055,
                0.19,
                0.48,
                0.725,
                1.88,
                1.88,
                1.855,
                1.935,
                2.1950002,
                2.595,
                3.3049998,
                4.115,
                3.37,
                2.97,
                3.32,
                3.5149999,
                3.56,
                3.44,
                3.355,
                3.3600001,
                3.32,
                3.32,
                3.4250002,
                3.42,
                3.3899999,
                3.445,
                3.3200002,
                3.0549998,
                4.58,
                4.01,
                3.02,
                2.79,
                2.75,
                2.76,
                2.855,
                2.99,
                2.96,
                2.775,
                2.595,
                2.4250002
              ],
              [
                -0.49,
                -0.26,
                -0.16,
                -0.09,
                -0.1,
                -0.13,
                -0.12,
                0.01,
                -0.07,
                0.17,
                0.44,
                0.66,
                1.84,
                1.85,
                1.83,
                1.9,
                2.15,
                2.55,
                3.27,
                4.11,
                3.46,
                2.96,
                3.31,
                3.5,
                3.55,
                3.42,
                3.33,
                3.34,
                3.29,
                3.29,
                3.43,
                3.44,
                3.42,
                3.52,
                3.41,
                3.11,
                4.53,
                4,
                3.01,
                2.79,
                2.76,
                2.77,
                2.87,
                3,
                2.93,
                2.71,
                2.53,
                2.38
              ]
            ],
            "gapFillRatio": 0
          }
        ],
        "level": "2 m above gnd",
        "aggregation": "none",
        "code": 11,
        "variable": "Temperature"
      }
    ],
    "timeIntervals": [
      [
        "20180101T0000",
        "20180101T0100",
        "20180101T0200",
        "20180101T0300",
        "20180101T0400",
        "20180101T0500",
        "20180101T0600",
        "20180101T0700",
        "20180101T0800",
        "20180101T0900",
        "20180101T1000",
        "20180101T1100",
        "20180101T1200",
        "20180101T1300",
        "20180101T1400",
        "20180101T1500",
        "20180101T1600",
        "20180101T1700",
        "20180101T1800",
        "20180101T1900",
        "20180101T2000",
        "20180101T2100",
        "20180101T2200",
        "20180101T2300",
        "20180102T0000",
        "20180102T0100",
        "20180102T0200",
        "20180102T0300",
        "20180102T0400",
        "20180102T0500",
        "20180102T0600",
        "20180102T0700",
        "20180102T0800",
        "20180102T0900",
        "20180102T1000",
        "20180102T1100",
        "20180102T1200",
        "20180102T1300",
        "20180102T1400",
        "20180102T1500",
        "20180102T1600",
        "20180102T1700",
        "20180102T1800",
        "20180102T1900",
        "20180102T2000",
        "20180102T2100",
        "20180102T2200",
        "20180102T2300"
      ]
    ],
    "timeResolution": "hourly"
  },
  {
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          24.7,
          59.4,
          31.73
        ],
        [
          24.8,
          59.4,
          36.445
        ]
      ],
      "locationNames": [
        "59.4°N/24.7°E31.7m",
        "59.4°N/24.8°E36.4m"
      ],
      "type": "MultiPoint"
    },
    "domain": "NEMS12",
    "codes": [
      {
        "unit": "°C",
        "aggregation": "none",
        "code": 11,
        "level": "1000 mb",
        "dataPerTimeInterval": [
          {
            "data": [
              [
                -0.585,
                -0.265,
                -0.055,
                0.04,
                0.044999998,
                0.08,
                0.11,
                0.205,
                0.13499999,
                0.43,
                0.84000003,
                1.2,
                2.1,
                2.33,
                2.5,
                2.72,
                3.1750002,
                3.775,
                4.915,
                5.37,
                4.16,
                3.795,
                4.1949997,
                4.41,
                4.415,
                4.275,
                4.1800003,
                4.16,
                4.0950003,
                4.08,
                4.185,
                4.1,
                3.98,
                3.575,
                3.22,
                2.92,
                4.395,
                3.7649999,
                2.895,
                2.66,
                2.6550002,
                2.72,
                2.845,
                2.955,
                2.89,
                2.685,
                2.54,
                2.355
              ],
              [
                -0.64,
                -0.29,
                -0.08,
                0.01,
                0.03,
                0.08,
                0.12,
                0.24,
                0.14,
                0.4,
                0.8,
                1.13,
                2.11,
                2.34,
                2.52,
                2.74,
                3.19,
                3.82,
                4.91,
                5.45,
                4.29,
                3.81,
                4.19,
                4.42,
                4.43,
                4.28,
                4.17,
                4.15,
                4.08,
                4.06,
                4.18,
                4.12,
                4.01,
                3.66,
                3.31,
                2.97,
                4.38,
                3.79,
                2.9,
                2.68,
                2.68,
                2.75,
                2.89,
                2.99,
                2.88,
                2.64,
                2.43,
                2.27
              ]
            ],
            "gapFillRatio": 0
          }
        ],
        "variable": "Temperature"
      }
    ],
    "timeIntervals": [
      [
        "20180101T0000",
        "20180101T0100",
        "20180101T0200",
        "20180101T0300",
        "20180101T0400",
        "20180101T0500",
        "20180101T0600",
        "20180101T0700",
        "20180101T0800",
        "20180101T0900",
        "20180101T1000",
        "20180101T1100",
        "20180101T1200",
        "20180101T1300",
        "20180101T1400",
        "20180101T1500",
        "20180101T1600",
        "20180101T1700",
        "20180101T1800",
        "20180101T1900",
        "20180101T2000",
        "20180101T2100",
        "20180101T2200",
        "20180101T2300",
        "20180102T0000",
        "20180102T0100",
        "20180102T0200",
        "20180102T0300",
        "20180102T0400",
        "20180102T0500",
        "20180102T0600",
        "20180102T0700",
        "20180102T0800",
        "20180102T0900",
        "20180102T1000",
        "20180102T1100",
        "20180102T1200",
        "20180102T1300",
        "20180102T1400",
        "20180102T1500",
        "20180102T1600",
        "20180102T1700",
        "20180102T1800",
        "20180102T1900",
        "20180102T2000",
        "20180102T2100",
        "20180102T2200",
        "20180102T2300"
      ]
    ],
    "timeResolution": "hourly"
  },
  {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "locationNames": [
        "59.4°N/24.7°E31.7m",
        "59.4°N/24.8°E36.4m"
      ],
      "coordinates": [
        [
          24.7,
          59.4,
          31.73
        ],
        [
          24.8,
          59.4,
          36.445
        ]
      ]
    },
    "domain": "NEMS12",
    "codes": [
      {
        "unit": "°C",
        "dataPerTimeInterval": [
          {
            "data": [
              [
                -7.0950003,
                -6.615,
                -4.815,
                -3.55,
                -2.6750002,
                -2.1950002,
                -2.695,
                -2.87,
                -2.1399999,
                -0.995,
                0.1,
                1,
                0.335,
                0.38,
                -0.030000001,
                -0.8,
                -0.18,
                0.575,
                1.11,
                -0.32999998,
                -1.03,
                -2.31,
                -3.09,
                -3.7350001,
                -3.93,
                -3.905,
                -3.92,
                -3.71,
                -3.625,
                -3.195,
                -3.7,
                -3.32,
                -3.72,
                -3.915,
                -3.93,
                -3.605,
                -4.315,
                -3.8899999,
                -3.815,
                -3.38,
                -3.2150002,
                -3.27,
                -3.435,
                -3.47,
                -3.43,
                -3.37,
                -3.44,
                -3.51
              ],
              [
                -7.11,
                -6.73,
                -4.94,
                -3.57,
                -2.7,
                -2.15,
                -2.62,
                -2.91,
                -2.22,
                -1.1,
                0.03,
                0.9,
                0.36,
                0.37,
                0.11,
                -0.74,
                -0.13,
                0.59,
                1.19,
                -0.19,
                -0.95,
                -2.18,
                -3.08,
                -3.68,
                -3.97,
                -3.94,
                -3.93,
                -3.69,
                -3.63,
                -3.27,
                -3.7,
                -3.32,
                -3.68,
                -3.9,
                -3.97,
                -3.6,
                -4.29,
                -3.92,
                -3.8,
                -3.37,
                -3.24,
                -3.28,
                -3.42,
                -3.44,
                -3.39,
                -3.35,
                -3.37,
                -3.44
              ]
            ],
            "gapFillRatio": 0
          }
        ],
        "level": "850 mb",
        "code": 11,
        "aggregation": "none",
        "variable": "Temperature"
      }
    ],
    "timeResolution": "hourly",
    "timeIntervals": [
      [
        "20180101T0000",
        "20180101T0100",
        "20180101T0200",
        "20180101T0300",
        "20180101T0400",
        "20180101T0500",
        "20180101T0600",
        "20180101T0700",
        "20180101T0800",
        "20180101T0900",
        "20180101T1000",
        "20180101T1100",
        "20180101T1200",
        "20180101T1300",
        "20180101T1400",
        "20180101T1500",
        "20180101T1600",
        "20180101T1700",
        "20180101T1800",
        "20180101T1900",
        "20180101T2000",
        "20180101T2100",
        "20180101T2200",
        "20180101T2300",
        "20180102T0000",
        "20180102T0100",
        "20180102T0200",
        "20180102T0300",
        "20180102T0400",
        "20180102T0500",
        "20180102T0600",
        "20180102T0700",
        "20180102T0800",
        "20180102T0900",
        "20180102T1000",
        "20180102T1100",
        "20180102T1200",
        "20180102T1300",
        "20180102T1400",
        "20180102T1500",
        "20180102T1600",
        "20180102T1700",
        "20180102T1800",
        "20180102T1900",
        "20180102T2000",
        "20180102T2100",
        "20180102T2200",
        "20180102T2300"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "locationNames": [
        "59.4°N/24.7°E31.7m",
        "59.4°N/24.8°E36.4m"
      ],
      "coordinates": [
        [
          24.7,
          59.4,
          31.73
        ],
        [
          24.8,
          59.4,
          36.445
        ]
      ]
    },
    "domain": "NEMS12",
    "codes": [
      {
        "unit": "°C",
        "dataPerTimeInterval": [
          {
            "data": [
              [
                -10.84,
                -12,
                -10.280001,
                -8.865,
                -8.5,
                -7.7,
                -7.5699997,
                -7.655,
                -8.434999,
                -8.844999,
                -8.700001,
                -7.1549997,
                -9.555,
                -10.004999,
                -7.885,
                -8.32,
                -8.370001,
                -8.915,
                -9.53,
                -10.225,
                -10.934999,
                -11.12,
                -11.434999,
                -11.575,
                -11.965,
                -11.64,
                -12.12,
                -12.345,
                -12.34,
                -12.48,
                -12.844999,
                -13.174999,
                -13.18,
                -13.219999,
                -13.434999,
                -13.305,
                -12.775,
                -12.745,
                -12.79,
                -12.75,
                -12.690001,
                -12.77,
                -12.77,
                -12.76,
                -12.67,
                -12.605,
                -12.635,
                -12.695
              ],
              [
                -10.74,
                -11.94,
                -10.54,
                -8.77,
                -8.56,
                -7.75,
                -7.52,
                -7.53,
                -8.24,
                -8.95,
                -8.77,
                -7.15,
                -9.48,
                -10.03,
                -7.88,
                -8.24,
                -8.35,
                -8.82,
                -9.4,
                -10.08,
                -10.84,
                -11.04,
                -11.3,
                -11.5,
                -11.9,
                -11.6,
                -12.09,
                -12.31,
                -12.39,
                -12.48,
                -12.83,
                -13.16,
                -13.2,
                -13.19,
                -13.4,
                -13.3,
                -12.77,
                -12.7,
                -12.78,
                -12.71,
                -12.66,
                -12.73,
                -12.73,
                -12.72,
                -12.62,
                -12.57,
                -12.6,
                -12.67
              ]
            ],
            "gapFillRatio": 0
          }
        ],
        "code": 11,
        "level": "700 mb",
        "aggregation": "none",
        "variable": "Temperature"
      }
    ],
    "timeResolution": "hourly",
    "timeIntervals": [
      [
        "20180101T0000",
        "20180101T0100",
        "20180101T0200",
        "20180101T0300",
        "20180101T0400",
        "20180101T0500",
        "20180101T0600",
        "20180101T0700",
        "20180101T0800",
        "20180101T0900",
        "20180101T1000",
        "20180101T1100",
        "20180101T1200",
        "20180101T1300",
        "20180101T1400",
        "20180101T1500",
        "20180101T1600",
        "20180101T1700",
        "20180101T1800",
        "20180101T1900",
        "20180101T2000",
        "20180101T2100",
        "20180101T2200",
        "20180101T2300",
        "20180102T0000",
        "20180102T0100",
        "20180102T0200",
        "20180102T0300",
        "20180102T0400",
        "20180102T0500",
        "20180102T0600",
        "20180102T0700",
        "20180102T0800",
        "20180102T0900",
        "20180102T1000",
        "20180102T1100",
        "20180102T1200",
        "20180102T1300",
        "20180102T1400",
        "20180102T1500",
        "20180102T1600",
        "20180102T1700",
        "20180102T1800",
        "20180102T1900",
        "20180102T2000",
        "20180102T2100",
        "20180102T2200",
        "20180102T2300"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "locationNames": [
        "59.4°N/24.7°E",
        "59.4°N/24.8°E"
      ],
      "coordinates": [
        [
          24.7,
          59.4,
          "NaN"
        ],
        [
          24.8,
          59.4,
          "NaN"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "domain": "CAMSGLOBAL",
    "codes": [
      {
        "unit": "",
        "dataPerTimeInterval": [
          {
            "data": [
              [
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN"
              ],
              [
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN",
                "NaN"
              ]
            ],
            "gapFillRatio": 0
          }
        ],
        "code": 706,
        "level": "sfc",
        "aggregation": "none",
        "variable": "Air Quality Index"
      }
    ],
    "timeResolution": "hourly",
    "timeIntervals": [
      [
        "20180101T0000",
        "20180101T0100",
        "20180101T0200",
        "20180101T0300",
        "20180101T0400",
        "20180101T0500",
        "20180101T0600",
        "20180101T0700",
        "20180101T0800",
        "20180101T0900",
        "20180101T1000",
        "20180101T1100",
        "20180101T1200",
        "20180101T1300",
        "20180101T1400",
        "20180101T1500",
        "20180101T1600",
        "20180101T1700",
        "20180101T1800",
        "20180101T1900",
        "20180101T2000",
        "20180101T2100",
        "20180101T2200",
        "20180101T2300",
        "20180102T0000",
        "20180102T0100",
        "20180102T0200",
        "20180102T0300",
        "20180102T0400",
        "20180102T0500",
        "20180102T0600",
        "20180102T0700",
        "20180102T0800",
        "20180102T0900",
        "20180102T1000",
        "20180102T1100",
        "20180102T1200",
        "20180102T1300",
        "20180102T1400",
        "20180102T1500",
        "20180102T1600",
        "20180102T1700",
        "20180102T1800",
        "20180102T1900",
        "20180102T2000",
        "20180102T2100",
        "20180102T2200",
        "20180102T2300"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your Edit #2 should be an answer for future readers. You *can* answer your own question. Accepting it takes a day or so IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Given your first example, you could then process it like this to separate the json array into individual objects and stuff them into a table as separate rows:

```
create table real_json as select value::jsonb from temp_json join lateral json_array_elements(values::json) on true;
```

However, this depends on the large single json object always being small enough to fit comfortably into an amount of memory you are willing to use, which seems like a dubious proposition.  You need a library which does incremental or streaming parsing on the JSON object, returning one 2nd level object at a time and then clearing it from memory one returned.  I don't think that PostgreSQL provides such a facility.  If you let us know what your favorite programming language is, perhaps someone can propose a specific library.

Alternatively, you could whip up a quick and dirty script that divides the JSON into lines for separate records based on the assumption that the indenting of the "pretty" file is always correct, and so using "^  [{}]" as markers, and then strips out the newlines to reverse the "pretty" formatting so that each record is a single line.  If you had such a script, you could then do:

```
\copy real_json FROM PROGRAM 'unnest_top_array_and_depretty /home/cae/test_without_new_lines.json';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look into the 2 solutions you've proposed most !

Preferred langage is C++, then I could work with some Python as well. I'm interested to hear from you about about those libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Same code of @jjanes with a real, working command line tool.

`\copy json_table FROM PROGRAM 'jq --stream -nc -f myfile.json';`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ''pretty format'' from the file helped in using the COPY function but it puts the whole content of the file in one row, making it impossible to run a simple SELECT query on an existing column ...

Here is what I used :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE target(data jsonb);
copy target from '/home/cae/test_without_new_lines.json';
```